# Visual Studio loading unrelated DLLs into my project when debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, wtl, norton

I have Norton 360 installed on my system. I run this WTL project(VS2012) in debug mode, and in the output window I see the following line

> 'CheckWTL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Norton360\NortonData\21.1.0.18\Definitions\BASHDefs\20140510.001\UMEngx86.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Why is a Norton dll loaded in my app. The app is still a basic skeleton and I have not added any code.

Any explanations?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a00ed805-e836-4ecc-a0ae-692eb95249c5/vb-c-2010-debug?forum=vcgeneral), the Norton DLL seems to be injected into every process that is started on the system.

Comment: Thats what I thought. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your anti-virus software is probably taking advantage of the `AppInit_DLL` feature in Windows which allows DLLs to be loaded into every user process, documentation here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744762(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744762%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If it is using the AppInit feature you can use a tool like Autoruns (available from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963902.aspx ) to remove the entry, however your AV software might detect this and forcefully re-install itself. I suggest disabling your AV software (or at least the real-time protection part of it) as per Symantec's instructions to avoid this in future.